# Why can't i assign some types in my settings.settings?

Tags: c#, settings, designer

While hacking some data into my settings.settings in VS 2010, i discovered i can use many different types from a variety of libraries i use, for example, the HTTPListener from the System.Net-namespace.

But for some strange reason i can't see why, i can't use the IPAddress-type, which i need actually.
Why is this so and how can i fix this, since for me, this is nothing more than an annoying bug.

I don't know what to try to fix this?

Comment: This is a guess but maybe they need to be serializable.

Comment: System.Net.IPAddress has the Serializable-Attribute. :/ Even more funny is, if you simply open the .settings-file with your code editor and hack the type in manully, the designer even accepts it if the Type exists. It doesn't save any changes in it, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> System.Net.IPAddress has the Serializable-Attribute

That's not relevant, [Serializable] only matters to binary serialization.  Settings are serialized with XML serialization.  Which is the core problem, that only works when the type has a default constructor.  So the deserializer can create a new object and set the public fields and properties.  IPAddress doesn't have one.

Consider using a simple string instead.  Use IPAddress.Parse() and ToString() in your code to convert.